# javafx textarea update and asynchronous calls?

Tags: java, asynchronous, javafx

I populate my Textarea from an external Datasource when a row in a 
table was selected. But the content in the area was sometimes not updated why? 
I have find me in programming frequently wizards with selections form list/table with crud functionality. Are there Frameworks how automate this process for creating this wizards in javafx?

```
 this.tablePresenter.getTable().getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Data>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Data> ov, Data n, Data newData) {
                if (newData != null) {
                        populateTextAreContent(service.getContent(newData.getData()));

        });
```

populateTextAreaContent(String s) becomes his content data from an external datasource as String Object and i bind the propert like. How i make this call async in javafx?

```
 private void populateTextAreaContent(String data) {
        StringProperty p = new SimpleStringProperty(data);
        this.textAreaPresenter.gettextArea().textProperty().bind(p);
    }
```

I use the afterburner framework from adam bien for my architecture.
And the Presenter for the Textarea is empty

public class TextArePresenter implements Initializable {

```
@FXML
private TextArea content;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
}

public TextArea gettextArea() {
    return content;
}
```

}